# Can not install Mono due to Package errors

Tags: mono

I'm trying to install OnlyOffice and they're require Mono to be installed. They way they AND mono recommend to install it on CentOS is to follow the RHEL/CentOS instructions at the bottom of this page:
 http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/
I've done so and when trying to install I run into this:

```
    Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libgdiplus0-3.12-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: libgdiplus0-3.12-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: libgdiplus0-3.12-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: libgdiplus0-3.12-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mono-core-3.12.0-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
Error: Package: libgdiplus0-3.12-0.x86_64 (download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have installed mono from source but the onlyoffice repo I'm required to use does not see it and I get :

```
Error: Package: onlyoffice-8.1.0-7.noarch (onlyoffice)
           Requires: mono >= 3.2.0
Error: Package: onlyoffice-8.1.0-7.noarch (onlyoffice)
           Requires: xsp
```

Any ideas on getting it to work?

Thanks